# toggle class to show cards

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

I am writing a memory game in JavaScript.
I am at the step where I should add `toggleClass`, so when the cards are clicked they will be shown.  I was told that I should solve this issue with `event.target`. When I click the cards are being shown, but in tiny icons and not in the boxes where they belong. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

```js
/*
 * Create a list that holds all of your cards
 */


/*
 * Display the cards on the page
 *   - shuffle the list of cards using the provided "shuffle" method below
 *   - loop through each card and create its HTML
 *   - add each card's HTML to the page
 */

// Shuffle function from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976

var myCard = ["fa fa-diamond", "fa fa-paper-plane-o", "fa fa-anchor", "fa fa-bolt", "fa fa-cube", "fa fa-leaf", "fa fa-bicycle", "fa fa-bomb"];



myCard.forEach(function(item) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var text = document.createTextNode(item);
  li.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
});

  function shuffle(myCard) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return myCard;
}
function handler(event) {
  var target = $( event.target );
  if ( target.is( "li" ) ) {
    target.children().toggle();
  }
}
/*$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").click(function(event) {
      $target = $(event.target);
      $target.toggleClass("card");
    });
  });



/*
/*
 * set up the event listener for a card. If a card is clicked:
 *  - display the card's symbol (put this functionality in another function that you call from this one)
 *  - add the card to a *list* of "open" cards (put this functionality in another function that you call from this one)
 *  - if the list already has another card, check to see if the two cards match
 *    + if the cards do match, lock the cards in the open position (put this functionality in another function that you call from this one)
 *    + if the cards do not match, remove the cards from the list and hide the card's symbol (put this functionality in another function that you call from this one)
 *    + increment the move counter and display it on the page (put this functionality in another function that you call from this one)
 *    + if all cards have matched, display a message with the final score (put this functionality in another function that you call from this one)
 */
```

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: #ffffff url('../img/geometry2.png'); /* Background pattern from Subtle Patterns */
    font-family: 'Coda', cursive;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

/*
 * Styles for the deck of cards
 */

.deck {
    width: 660px;
    min-height: 680px;
    background: linear-gradient(160deg, #02ccba 0%, #aa7ecd 100%);
    padding: 32px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 12px 15px 20px 0 rgba(46, 61, 73, 0.5);
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 0 3em;
}

.deck .card {
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
    background: #2e3d49;
    font-size: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 5px 2px 20px 0 rgba(46, 61, 73, 0.5);
}

.deck .card.open {
    transform: rotateY(0);
    background: #02b3e4;
    cursor: default;
}

.deck .card.show {
    font-size: 33px;
}

.deck .card.match {
    cursor: default;
    background: #02ccba;
    font-size: 33px;
}

/*
 * Styles for the Score Panel
 */

.score-panel {
    text-align: left;
    width: 345px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.score-panel .stars {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.score-panel .stars li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.score-panel .restart {
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="deck">
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card match">
                <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card match">
                <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card open show">
                <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul id="myUL">
    </ul>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You really should reduce all that the most simple form of the problem at hand.

Comment: if using JQuery, give a try `$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).on("click", "li", function(){
    $(this).toggle();
  });
});`

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.It is much appreciated.Unfortunately will not show the cards.When i click on each card the box simply dissapears.Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: I would like to mention it that if i add "show" than the cards are shown,but I am not sure that this solution will help me to build the game and and to work as it should    $(this).toggleClass("show");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register the `.deck` to the click event. Note: the second parameter **`.card`**

```
$('.deck').on('click', '.card', handler)
```

The handler "knows" that any `.card` is `e.target` and `this` due to the previously noted second parameter above. `toggleClass()` the `.open` and `.show` classes **not** the `.card`. The `.card` style must be maintained and the `.open` and `.show` classes are responsible for animation and the second "state" (first state is facedown, the second state is faceup).

```
function handler(event) {
  $(this).toggleClass('open show');
};
```

Also I added the animation in CSS as well. If you use `transform` use `transition` to animate it.

### Demo

```js
/*
 * Create a list that holds all of your cards
 */


/*
 * Display the cards on the page
 *   - shuffle the list of cards using the provided "shuffle" method below
 *   - loop through each card and create its HTML
 *   - add each card's HTML to the page
 */

// Shuffle function from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976

var myCard = ["fa fa-diamond", "fa fa-paper-plane-o", "fa fa-anchor", "fa fa-bolt", "fa fa-cube", "fa fa-leaf", "fa fa-bicycle", "fa fa-bomb"];



myCard.forEach(function(item) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var text = document.createTextNode(item);
  li.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
});

function shuffle(myCard) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  while (currentIndex !== 0) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return myCard;
}
/* Register the .deck to the click event */
// Note: the second parameter .card
$('.deck').on('click', '.card', handler)

/* The handler "knows" that any .card is e.target and this */
// toggleClass the .open and .show classes
function handler(event) {
  $(this).toggleClass('open show');
};

/*$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").click(function(event) {
      $target = $(event.target);
      $target.toggleClass("card");
    });
  });



/*
/*
 * set up the event listener for a card. If a card is clicked:
 *  - display the card's symbol (put this functionality in another function that you call from this one)
 *  - add the card to a *list* of "open" cards (put this functionality in another function that you call from this one)
 *  - if the list already has another card, check to see if the two cards match
 *    + if the cards do match, lock the cards in the open position (put this functionality in another function that you call from this one)
 *    + if the cards do not match, remove the cards from the list and hide the card's symbol (put this functionality in another function that you call from this one)
 *    + increment the move counter and display it on the page (put this functionality in another function that you call from this one)
 *    + if all cards have matched, display a message with the final score (put this functionality in another function that you call from this one)
 */
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #ffffff url('../img/geometry2.png');
  /* Background pattern from Subtle Patterns */
  font-family: 'Coda', cursive;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}


/*
 * Styles for the deck of cards
 */

.deck {
  width: 660px;
  min-height: 680px;
  background: linear-gradient(160deg, #02ccba 0%, #aa7ecd 100%);
  padding: 32px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 12px 15px 20px 0 rgba(46, 61, 73, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 0 3em;
}

.deck .card {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  background: #2e3d49;
  font-size: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 5px 2px 20px 0 rgba(46, 61, 73, 0.5);
  /* This is animation for a card going to default state */
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.deck .card.open {
  background: #02b3e4;
  cursor: default;
  /* This is animation for a card when coming from default */
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.deck .card.show {
  font-size: 33px;
}

.deck .card.match {
  cursor: default;
  background: #02ccba;
  font-size: 33px;
}


/*
 * Styles for the Score Panel
 */

.score-panel {
  text-align: left;
  width: 345px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.score-panel .stars {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.score-panel .stars li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.score-panel .restart {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<ul class="deck">
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card match">
    <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card match">
    <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card open show">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul id="myUL">
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for adding the animation as well  this solved my issue and now the cards are showing

Comment: You are very welcome, it looks good. When you are finalizing it, designing the backside as it flips would be a nice touch.

Comment: Thank you for the idea :) will play around with it

Comment: Nice animations :D thank you for the idea and for your time

Answer (score 0):

In your commented out click handler you are using event.target which is pure JavaScript.  Better off using the "this" object to identify the element being clicked. There is also a syntax error and some unnecessary stuff. Try replacing with this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("card");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I have tried using your code,but I am getting the same issue,the small icons(font awesome)gets out of the boxes when clicked,instead of being shown in larger size inside the box,I will post a screenshot of how it looks.Maybe you got any other idea?Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vAJG.jpg)when clicking on the cards they are shown in tiny icons instead of showing up in the right box[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkfyJ.jpg)